# How to enable ASLR in Xcode for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, aslr

The question is simple:

How can I enable ASLR on my Xcode iOS project?

I don't find any ASLR options in the target settings.

Comment: ASLR or ALSR ? I think you mean ASLR. Why would you enable it ? Everything is handled by iOS and I think it is at kernel level.

Comment: We had a security audit and one of the remarks was, I quote: "The application does not enforce ASLR binary protection."

They checked using otool: -->  NOUNDEFS DYLDLINK TWOLEVEL PIE

Comment: Joris even in my company they are doing security audit. Did you found any solution how to enable ASLR in Xcode project ?

Answer (score 1):

> ASLR is an important exploit mitigation technique introduced in iOS
>   4.3. ASLR makes the remote exploitation of memory corruption vulnerabilities significantly more difficult by randomizing the
>   application objects’ location in the memory. By default, iOS
>   applications use limited ASLR and only randomize part of the objects
>   in the memory.

Follow the [link](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/penetration-testing-for-iphone-applications-part-5/#gref) where deply describe about ASLR and may be you can find solution.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the fact that PIE is included means the app is built with ASLR? otool shows "PIE" in its output, on my build.

Comment: PIE is for Position Independent Execution.